# Get translation text from Laravel to use in i18n nextjs

Tags: laravel, i18next

I am building Laravel app as server side and admin panel, and NextJs as client side. I also export my translation file from laravel to use in NextJs also that in NextJs I use I18n.

But when I use translation text that has parameter it not correct format with I18n

for example in my translation file I have key translate

```
//file common.php
return [
   'greeting' => 'Hi, :name'
]
```

So when I use it in laravel

```
__('common.greeting', ['name' => 'Jonh']); // result will be "Hi, Jonh"
```

But when I use it in my Nextjs

```
t('common:greeting', { name: 'Jonh' })
```

it display "Hi, :name"

Does i18n has some config to make translation text from laravel can work with i18n

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to i18next options:

```
interpolation: {
  prefixEscaped: ':\\b', // start with : and follow by word boundary
  suffixEscaped: '(?:\\b)' // match with word boundary as suffix but don't capture it
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the parameter represents

in NextJs I18n the parameter should be like this

```
'Hi, {{name}}'
```

not this

```
'Hi, :name'
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: But this 'Hi, :name' was used in laravel app e.g `__('common.greating', ['name' => ;Jonh'])` . we don't want to duplicate that value to fit with nextjs by create other value as 'Hi, {{name}}'